# What does `LOGFILE=${1:-/var/log/syslog}` do?

Tags: command-line, bash

I stumbled across [this script](https://sourceforge.net/p/yad-dialog/wiki/LogViewer/) containing:

```
LOGFILE=${1:-/var/log/syslog}
```

What does this line do?

Comment: Closely related: [What is the meaning of ${GZIP_BINDIR-'/bin'} in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/628849/507051)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command: `LOGFILE=${1:-/var/log/syslog}` is shorthand for:

```bash
if [[ "$1" == "" ]]               # if parameter 1 is blank
then
    LOGFILE="/var/log/syslog"     # LOGFILE set to /var/log/syslog
else
    LOGFILE="$1"                  # LOGFILE set to parameter 1
fi
```

If parameter 1 is not passed you see:

[image: yad-logfile 1.png]

If you pass paraemeter 1:

```bash
journalctl -b > /tmp/messages
yad-logfile /tmp/messages
```

you see:

[image: yad-logfile 2.png]

---

The original code in [question link](https://sourceforge.net/p/yad-dialog/wiki/LogViewer/) was modified:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: yad-logfile
# DATE: May 19, 2019.

# From: https://sourceforge.net/p/yad-dialog/wiki/LogViewer/

# This script demonstrates new features of list dialog. Script displays content
# of specified log file and mark some special strings: with word "kernel" by
# setting italic font, with word "error" by light yellow background and with
# word "warn" by pink background 

LOGFILE=${1:-/var/log/syslog}

 PARSER='{font=""; color="#FFFFFF"}; \
/CRON/   {font="italic"}; \
/smartd/ {color="#FFF4B8"}; \
/upower/ {color="#FFD0D8"}; \
OFS="\n" {print $1 " " $2, $3, $4, substr($5,0,index($5,":")-1), \
substr($0,index($0,$6)), font, color; fflush()}'

cat $LOGFILE | awk "$PARSER" | \
yad --title="Log viewer" --window-icon=logviewer \
    --button=gtk-close --geometry 600x350 \
    --list --text="Content of $LOGFILE" \
    --column Date --column Time --column Host \
    --column Tag --column Message:TIP \
    --column @font@ --column @back@

exit $?
```

Comment: IMHO if [[ "$1" == "" ]]  is not entirely equivalent. This tries to expand $1, whereas parameter expansion is intended for cases where $1 was not defined or unset. It is far more useful with environment variables like HOME for cases when they may be missing. Setting a variable to empty string in this code would produce similar effect but is not the same no variable in environment.